# How to display all even numbers less than a given number?

Tags: java, loops

I need to display all even numbers for that are less than a specific number. Those numbers are random generated between a range. Here's the assignment:

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer (n). Your program generates then, another random
>   integer (max) that reaches at most 10 * n. So if n entered was 5, the number generated (max) should be
>   between 5 and 50 (5*10). This program displays the sum of all even numbers less than (max). Your program
>   stops at the first sum value reached greater than max. Display its value.

What I have done so far:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

int n = s.nextInt();
int most = (10 * n) - (n+1);
int max = (int)( n + Math.random() * most);

System.out.println("Maximum generated is: "+ max);

for(int i = 2 ; i < max; i+=2) {
    int num = max/i;
    if(num % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("number is "+ num);
    }    
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter an integer: 5
Maximum generated is: 45
Sum of (6 8 10 12) = 50 //we stopped because 50 is the first sum greater
                        //than max
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Use Tags section for tags, do not put tags in Title section. I sanitized your question.

Comment: I think the idea is to generate all the even numbers less than max (2 through 48) and then sum them all.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes exactly

Comment: The for loop is unnecessarily complex. All you need to do is to sum the even numbers. You won't need division or modulus for that. I recommend you to start the loop from scratch and think more, type less.

Comment: @kviiri will do , then i'll update the post with what i have done.. thanks :)

Comment: @AayKay good luck, and keep it simple! :)

Comment: Also, note that for a sum like `2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 16 + 18 + 20` there's a closed form, since it's equal to `(20 + 2) + (18 + 4) + ...  (12 + 10) == k * 22` for some `k`.  It's a little bit trickier if there are an odd number of even numbers, but not by much.  I point this out because even though you tagged the question with [tag:loops], the problem description doesn't actually mandate the use of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic should like this,

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 2;
while (i<max) {
    sum+=i;
    if (sum > max) {
        break;
    }
    i+=2;
}
System.out.print("Value=" + sum);
```

Comment: That's how i was thinking inside my loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<max; i=i+2){
  sum+=i;
}
```

System.out.println(sum);
It does however sound like there might be an even faster dirrect mathametical formula for fonding the sum of all even numbers bellow a certain number but that's a question for another stack exchange.